# Datepicker not displaying current date/month

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using [vue-dropdown-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dropdown-datepicker) and what I want it not to have any previous date, it does allow option of `allowPast` which I set to false but it only remove previous year.

Is there a way I can use it to show current date/month and year?

```
<dropdown-datepicker
                :allowPast="allowPast"
                name="Data"
                defaultDateFormat="dd-mm-yyyy"
                submitFormat="dd-mm-yyyy"
                month-format="short"
                display-format="dmy"
/>
```

Comment: If you can create a snippet I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I tried to use codesandbox but it won't search for the plugin but [here](https://tanvir0604.github.io/vue-dropdown-datepicker/) are some example

Comment: Yeah and looking at the code allowPast should not display the past years and in the current year should not allow the previous months (see populateYear, populateMonth functions on github). There seems to be something wrong with the options/configuration you pass. The 18 year example looks fine too.

Comment: @Edub yes, I removed all option expect, allowPast: false, allowFuture: true yet it showing all months.

Comment: Hard to see where the problem is without a snippet. As mentioned above this would help to look into it.

Comment: @Edub https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-nobel-j2dk0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue here u go with a working example, the month list is displayed as full whereas `allowPast:false`

Answer (score 0):

Having fiddled with the example I noticed that in the examples they bind the min-date as follows

```
v-bind:min-date="minDate"
```

If you do the same with the allowPast which as a attribute must be allow-past a lot of ui frameworks bind camelCase options like that. I think attributes are case insensitive and therefore they transform them with a '-'. So adjusting your example as follows sets the options correctly and works.

```
v-bind:allow-past="false"
```

Comment: Do u have a link to sandbox? seem mine doesn't work.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pine-6vprf?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: It only filters months when I select year. What I want to have the months already filtered  (meaning no past) as year is 2020

Comment: Yeah then preselect the year 2020 or set the default date to today. The plugin seems buggy for today so you have to set the time to 23:59:59 or smth like that https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pine-6vprf?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
But yeah basically it's another problem :-)

Comment: sweet. what is that format called? I can generate it  dynamically so it is not hard coded

Comment: Should be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 what I tried. Maybe the documentation for the plugin specifies a "correct" format for the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217020/discussion-between-nofel-and-edub).